# authentication method for likewise to join a domain

Tags: authentication, active-directory, likewise, kerberos

I installed likewise and joined my an active directory domain.
I'm finding it's a bit unclear on how the default authentication works.

Do I have to do any extra configuration to enable kerberos?
If I do, then what authentication method is default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well try this before installing likewise-open

**Open Terminal**

ping domain e.g. domain.com
ping doimain controller e.g. domaincontroller.domain.com
ping domain controller IP Address 192.168.X.X

**For this Process I used ¨root user¨**

$ sudo su

gedit /etc/hosts

**Put this below the first two lines:**

IPADDRESSOFDCSERVER   SERVERNAME
192.168.0.1       Ubuntuserver1

gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf

**look for line that says hosts and comment is out with ¨#¨
then add the following line above it:**

hosts:      files dns mdns4

gedit /etc/resolv.conf

**comment out everything with ¨#¨ and add line below**

search domain.com
nameserver  192.168.X.X (IP ADDRESS OF DOMAIN CONTROLLER)

gedit /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf

**Then add line below the ¨option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;¨**

supersede domain-name ¨domain.com¨;

prepend domain-name-servers 192.168.0.2; (IP ADDRESS OF DOMAIN CONTROLLER)

**Here I added the user I will be log into the machine with to a two group:**

sudo visudo

under #User privilege specification: put domain user
DOMAIN\username ALL=(ALL) ALL

**and**

under #Member of admin group may gain root privileges:

%DOMAIN\domain^users ALL=(ALL) ALL

**Then Install likewise with the following:**

apt-get install likewise-open likewise-open-gui

**Then join the domain:**

domainjoin-cli join --ou COMPUTERS DOMAIN.COM administrator

**This is opitional to allow you to just type in the username without the domain:**

lwconfig assumeDefaultDomain True

**Then you reboot the machine:**

sudo reboot

**After reboot you login:**

login with domain username

**from terminal you now check to see if all configuration went well:**

lw-get-status (to see if active Directory is there)

lw-enum-users (to see the user of active Directory)

**If errors should occur like not seeing the login page:**

Enable domain login on login screen

gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

**Acutally adding:** greeter-hide-users=true **(this hide the users so becareful with this one)**

greeter-show-manual-login=true **(This shows all users and login function)**

**To leave the domain**

sudo domainjoin-cli leave

Let me know if this helps!