# How to join a Ubuntu 12.04 machine to a Windows domain

Tags: domain-server

No matter how you try, sometimes you can't escape the clutches of Microsoft and Windows. I am trying to add my ubuntu 12.04 to my domain at work and make sure my user profile have sudo privileges.

Comment: Try this, https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/336477:how-to-join-a-ubuntu-machine-to-a-windows-domain. I managed to connect to My work Domain with ease.

Answer (score 1):

- install likewise-open

`apt-get install likewise-open`

- edit lightdm.conf to enable user and password GUI

`nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

- add the below lines

allow-guest=false

greeter-show-manual-login=true

- edit nsswitch.conf

files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4

- join domain

`sudo domainjoin-cli join example.local Administrator`

Comment: LikewiseOpen is now Beyond Trust - PowerBroker Identity Services Open Edition - [LikewiseOpen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen)

Answer (score 0):

**TWO THINGS:**

1. Make sure your username IS NOT your directory username. Just helps in the long run.
2. Add your domain username to sudo after if you wish to run commands.

I followed [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DirectControl) on my Ubuntu 12.04 to join a domain. It works great!

Use

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ natty partner" # Adds the Partner repository which has the active directory package in it to your system.
sudo apt-get install centrifydc # installs the package
sudo adjoin -w domain.name # joins domain
adinfo # verifies join was successful
ssh username@hostname # Confirm you can still ssh
ssh username.domain@hostname.domain #Confirm you can ssh with AD
```

Comment: I actually found a way with likewise-open which is much simpler

Comment: You should post it as an answer then. @dwaynekdclarke

Comment: here you go http://askubuntu.com/questions/311208/authentication-method-for-likewise-to-join-a-domain/424458#424458